# Call a variable from another model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to ask a little question. It's rather trivial I guess but I might just look for the wrong solutions to my issue so I cant get it working.

I have a model called **request.rb** which has a method called self.dates

```
def self.dates
     from_date = Request.last.date.to_date 
     to_date = Request.last.todate.to_date 
     weekdays = (from_date..to_date).select { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday)}.count
     weekend_days = (from_date..to_date).select { |d| [0, 6].include?(d.wday)}.count
end
```

I have another model called **hotels.rb** where I'd like to call the variables weekdays and weekend_days for the price calculation.

```
 def self.best_deal_nm
    weekday_nm_tot = (Request.dates.weekdays * pricea.wdpricenm) + (Request.dates.weekdays *  pricea.wepricenm)
    weekend_nm_tot = (Request.dates.weekend_days * priceb.wdpricenm) + (Request.dates.weekend_days * priceb.wepricenm)

    [weekday_nm_tot, weekend_nm_tot].min

  end
```

Unfortunately the code above doesnt work. My question is therefore how can I possibly call these two variables in my hotel model.

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return all info in last line into your `self.dates` method like

```
def self.dates
 from_date = Request.last.date.to_date 
 to_date = Request.last.todate.to_date 
 weekdays = (from_date..to_date).select { |d| (1..5).include?(d.wday)}.count
 weekend_days = (from_date..to_date).select { |d| [0, 6].include?(d.wday)}.count
 {'from_date' => from_date, 'to_date' => to_date, 'weekdays' => weekdays, 'weekend_days' => weekend_days}
end
```

After call `Request.dates` from `hotels.rb` you could access to all variables added to hash.

```
weekday_nm_tot = (Request.dates['weekdays'] * pricea.wdpricenm) + (Request.dates['weekdays'] *  pricea.wepricenm)
```